# Numbering Column Records in Ordered Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table Schema:

```
StatusId    Status  DisplayColor    IsOpen  DivisionId  SortOrder
4           Open    3e696c          1       34          1
5           Closed  3e696c          0       34          2
1           Open    3e696c          1       35          1
2           Closed  3e696c          0       35          2
```

The SQL Query I have to order the columns the way I need to number them:

```
select  StatusId, Status, DisplayColor, IsOpen, DivisionId, SortOrder
from    TV_Statuses s
order by DivisionId, IsOpen desc
```

I'm trying to create a script that can go through and assign SortOrder incrementally by DivisionId and then IsOpen. So here, STatusId of 4 would have a SortOrder of 1. StatusId of 5 would have SortOrder 2. The same for the bottom 2 rows, but here a division could have 100 rows, 70 open and 30 closed so the open would be numbered 1 - 70 and the Closed would be 71 - 100.

Any advice on a way to do this without resorting to cursors? My spidey sense tells me there's probably a more straightforward way to do it.

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: 
OK, so actually in the database now, the SortOrder column only has NULLs in it. I want to update the SortOrder column so that each Division (using DivisionId) has an incrementing number in SortOrder. For instance above DivisioniId of 34 has to rows with one IsOPen = 1 and one IsOpen = 0. So I would want to order those two rows with SortOrder 1 and 2 respectively. 
But a division could have 10 rows. Then that divisions SortOrder fields would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. 
It's hard to explain but hopefully that helps a little.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?  The logic seems to be inconsistent.  You say statusid 5 would have a value of 2.  Then you say closed would be 71-100.

Comment: Update sortorder to divisionid * 10 + 1 - isopen. This will result in sortorder that isn't continuous but you can still sort by it

Comment: Refer to my edits above. That might make it more clear. Again, right now my SortOrder columns are all NULL. I want to get them changed as they appear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2005 you can apply windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` to a set (or a subset, often called a partition but not to be confused with table partitioning). I believe what you are looking for is the following:

```
SELECT 
  StatusId, Status, DisplayColor, IsOpen, DivisionId, 
  SortOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY DivisionId ORDER BY IsOpen DESC, StatusId)
FROM dbo.TV_Statuses AS s
ORDER BY DivisionId, IsOpen DESC;
```

Comment: YES. After running the query you provided, that's exactly what I needed. Now I can just wrap that in a nested query and update my table. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @user1431725 why would you update the table? This is something you can always generate with a query like the one I've provided, and it will always be up to date. If you update the table, you will have to constantly update it to keep it up to date...

Comment: Negative. There's UI logic in place that will keep things ordered on record insertion/deletion and re-ordering. This is a one-time thing to get all the existing records in the database setup.

Comment: Still seems silly to store that (and have the app figure it out to store it) if you can determine it at query time based on existing information in the table.

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree. However I'm working with an existing project that I just took over. And, true to form, there's only two hours allocated to get it working. *sadface*